# string confused with a date. ToDouble issue in C#

Tags: c#, string, datetime, double, type-conversion

i have a simple conversion in C# from string ToDouble as shown in the image.
The exception thrown speaks of a datetime conversion, but neither the string resembles a date, not the variable assigned to is a DateTime variable. Can somebody help?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Please post code and exceptions as Text, not as pictures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.Convert.ToDouble` will use [`double.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.parse.aspx) with  the current culture by default. If your decimal separator is not `.` you might get this exception.

The `DateTime` thing  is misleading  since intellisense just tries to help you. Actually it's a number and not a `DateTime`. So it's not your fault but the Visual-Studio team could improve this message. The `FormatException`'s `Message` property does not contain `DateTime`.

It sounds like you want the invariant culture:

```
double d = double.Parse("0.0005", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

If you're not sure if the format is valid you should use [`double.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.tryparse.aspx):

```
double d;
if (double.TryParse("0.0005", NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out d))
{
    Console.Write("Value is: " + d);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The conversion depends on your country and culture settings.

If your are not in a country that uses a `.` as a decimal point, you should use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` as a second parameter to your conversion. Alternatively, you can specify the number in your native culture, but that is prone to problems when you give your application to someone using another culture on his PC.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of why you are getting the error... but have you tried something like this? If so does it give same error?

i.e. double.Parse will use the current culture by default. Have a read [of the answer posted by Mr Skeet in this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6800418/c-sharp-convert-todouble-format-exception-error)

```
string sVal ="0.0005"; 
double dVal = 0.0;

if (double.TryParse(sVal, out dVal))
{
    // Success !!
}
else
{
    // Could not convert
}
```